# When does vb.net duplicate data and when does it reference it?

Tags: vb.net

I'm dealing with big arrays, lots get dynamically created and destroyed as it is. Now i'm starting to build the processing bit of the class and want to avoid as much unnecessary slowdowns as possible.

My specific question would be: If I create a function that fetches an array by its name, would it pass on the reference to the array(desired) or create a duplicate array and give out that instead? Is there any way to control this?

Here is the code I am working with:

```
 public function fetchArrayByName(name as string) as single()
      for i = 0 to channels.count-1
           if channelnames(i) = name then return channel(i)
      next i
      return nothing
 end function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not specified, ByVal is implied, but it's really a reference to the array. So you cannot override the pointer inside the method, but you can change the object to which it points. To sum up, arrays, like classes, are actually passed by reference, no duplicate array will be created.

An official reference: [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Unofficial, with user comments: [Array ByVal or ByRef in VB.NET?](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?238975-Array-ByVal-or-ByRef-in-VB-NET)

Comment: Reference types are not passed by reference unless the method to which they're passed specifies the argument with the ByRef keyword.  If a reference type is passed to a method with the ByVal keyword in the method signature or if the keyword is omitted, it is passed by value, since that is the default.  In the case of a reference type passed by value, a copy of the reference is passed.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: Yes, I know. But if I wrote it like that, it would be overwhelming to the OP. I think the above is more clear. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

An array is a reference type in .NET, so your function will return a reference to the array.

If you wanted a brand new array, you'd have to make a copy yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an example would help:

```
Module Module1

    Dim channels As New Dictionary(Of String, Single())
    Function GetChannel(name As String) As Single()
        If channels.ContainsKey(name) Then
            Return channels(name)
        End If
        Return Nothing

    End Function

    Function GetShallowCopyOfChannel(name As String) As Single()
        If channels.ContainsKey(name) Then
            'TODO: if a deep clone is required, implement it.
            Dim newChannel = channels(name).Clone()
            Return CType(newChannel, Single())
        End If
        Return Nothing

    End Function
    Sub Main()

        channels.Add("English", {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4})
        channels.Add("Columbia River", {10.01, 11.11, 12.21, 13.31})

        Dim ch = GetChannel("English")

        If ch IsNot Nothing Then
            ch(0) = 999
            ' shows 999 as the first element, i.e. ch is the original array
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", channels("English")))
        Else
            'something went wrong
        End If

        ch = GetShallowCopyOfChannel("Columbia River")
        If ch IsNot Nothing Then
            ch(0) = 17
            ' shows 10.01 as the first element, i.e. ch is not the original array
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", channels("Columbia River")))
            ' shows 17 as the first element, i.e. ch is a an array separate from the original
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", ch))
        Else
            'something went wrong
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

If you're concerned with unnecessary slowdowns and you have a lot of arrays, you might like to use a Dictionary to store the arrays as it is implemented as a hashtable.